# How to get #EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME from JWPlayer

Tags: jwplayer

I'm struggling to retrieve the value of #EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME from a live HLS stream using JWPlayer 8.2. If I capture the 'on meta' JW event for a VOD stream, I can see a programDateTime parameter/value which is what I'm looking for, but on a live stream JW does't seem to provide it, even though the manifest file contains it.

Here's a sample of the VOD manifest file:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:4
## Created with Unified Streaming Platform(version=1.7.25)
#EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:VOD
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:190527336
#EXT-X-INDEPENDENT-SEGMENTS
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:8
#USP-X-TIMESTAMP-MAP:MPEGTS=7016782483,LOCAL=2018-04-20T10:04:42.023600Z
#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:2018-04-20T10:04:42.023683Z
#EXTINF:8.008, no desc
live-video=8000000-190527336.ts?token=abcco|2018-04-24T13:08:07Z|RufAWBYsJCTRTc06E%2BtSvg==|038cd04f1e982ce33e16702639268381ede1652e&amp%3Bt=2018-04-20T11:04:38-2018-04-20T10:05:16
#EXTINF:7.9914, no desc
live-video=8000000-190527337.ts?token=abcco|2018-04-24T13:08:07Z|RufAWBYsJCTRTc06E%2BtSvg==|038cd04f1e982ce33e16702639268381ede1652e&amp%3Bt=2018-04-20T11:04:38-2018-04-20T10:05:16
#EXTINF:8.008, no desc
live-video=8000000-190527338.ts?token=abcco|2018-04-24T13:08:07Z|RufAWBYsJCTRTc06E%2BtSvg==|038cd04f1e982ce33e16702639268381ede1652e&amp%3Bt=2018-04-20T11:04:38-2018-04-20T10:05:16
#EXTINF:7.9913, no desc
live-video=8000000-190527339.ts?token=abcco|2018-04-24T13:08:07Z|RufAWBYsJCTRTc06E%2BtSvg==|038cd04f1e982ce33e16702639268381ede1652e&amp%3Bt=2018-04-20T11:04:38-2018-04-20T10:05:16
#EXTINF:1.7684, no desc
live-video=8000000-190527340.ts?token=abcco|2018-04-24T13:08:07Z|RufAWBYsJCTRTc06E%2BtSvg==|038cd04f1e982ce33e16702639268381ede1652e&amp%3Bt=2018-04-20T11:04:38-2018-04-20T10:05:16
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

...and the JW on meta payload:

```
meta= {
        "duration": 33.7671,
        "height": 480,
        "width": 853,
        "seekRange": {
            "start": 0,
            "end": 33.7671
            },
        "type": "meta"
    }
meta= {
        "programDateTime": "2018-04-20T10:04:42.023683Z",
        "type": "meta
    }
```

...and a sample of the LIVE manifest:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:4
## Created with Unified Streaming Platform(version=1.7.25)
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:190571398
#EXT-X-INDEPENDENT-SEGMENTS
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:8
#USP-X-TIMESTAMP-MAP:MPEGTS=4382044205,LOCAL=2018-04-24T11:59:42.024600Z
#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:2018-04-24T11:59:42.024683Z
#EXTINF:8.008, no desc
live-video=8000000-190571398.ts?token=abcco|2018-04-24T13:00:13Z|RufAWBYsJCTRTc06E%2BtSvg==|b57a1e57d55685deb9aff6ad41292f1053d7294f
#EXTINF:7.9914, no desc
live-video=8000000-190571399.ts?token=abcco|2018-04-24T13:00:13Z|RufAWBYsJCTRTc06E%2BtSvg==|b57a1e57d55685deb9aff6ad41292f1053d7294f
#EXTINF:8.008, no desc
live-video=8000000-190571400.ts?token=abcco|2018-04-24T13:00:13Z|RufAWBYsJCTRTc06E%2BtSvg==|b57a1e57d55685deb9aff6ad41292f1053d7294f
#EXTINF:7.9913, no desc
live-video=8000000-190571401.ts?token=abcco|2018-04-24T13:00:13Z|RufAWBYsJCTRTc06E%2BtSvg==|b57a1e57d55685deb9aff6ad41292f1053d7294f
#EXTINF:8.008, no desc
live-video=8000000-190571402.ts?token=abcco|2018-04-24T13:00:13Z|RufAWBYsJCTRTc06E%2BtSvg==|b57a1e57d55685deb9aff6ad41292f1053d7294f
#EXTINF:7.9913, no desc
live-video=8000000-190571403.ts?token=abcco|2018-04-24T13:00:13Z|RufAWBYsJCTRTc06E%2BtSvg==|b57a1e57d55685deb9aff6ad41292f1053d7294f
#EXTINF:8.008, no desc
live-video=8000000-190571404.ts?token=abcco|2018-04-24T13:00:13Z|RufAWBYsJCTRTc06E%2BtSvg==|b57a1e57d55685deb9aff6ad41292f1053d7294f
```

...and the on meta payload:

```
meta= {
        "duration": null,
        "height": 480,
        "width": 853,
        "seekRange": {
            "start": 0,
            "end": 88.0046
            },
        "type": "meta"
    }
```

As you can see #EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME is provided in both manifest files, but I haven't found a way to extract the value for live.

Any thoughts or assistance would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not much of an answer here, but the metadata seems to depend on the live stream itself. I just checked the on('meta') response object of a live stream in JW 8.2.3 and I see:

```
{  
   "metadataTime":123.00226666666667,
   "metadata":{  
      "PRIV":{  
         "com.cisco.streaming.Timecode.0":"\t\u0013ٸ̐踐"
      },
      "width":320,
      "height":180,
      "duration":null
   },
   "type":"meta"
}
```